# How to get an HTML element's (i.e., a Div) top to start exactly at the bottom of its parent element using CSS

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is have a child element start directly at the bottom of a parent element. I know this question has been asked on here plenty of times, but I've been reading through those answers and every solution doesn't solve mine. They essentially all say to put the parent element to "position: relative" and the child element to "position: absolute", which is I'm sure is true, and that I'm just still missing something.

First, see my React code (very simple code only for this learning purpose):

```
import './App.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="d1">
        <ul className="ul1">
          <li className="li1">Home</li>
          <li className="li1">About</li>
          <li className="li1">Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now see my CSS code:

```
.App {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.d1 {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 80px;
  min-width: 100px;

}

.ul1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  top: 100%;

}
```

Now see snip below. What I want is for the green outlined list to start at exactly the bottom of the blue highlighted div. The top image is what I'm able to get. The bottom image if what I want to achieve Note that I hardcoded the position on the bottom image, so that's how I'm able to get it just for this snip. In practice, I want it to dynamically show at that location.

[image: What I'm able to achieve]
[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: To get an HTML element's top to start exactly at the bottom of its parent element using CSS, you can use the position and top properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ul1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  top: 100%;
/* add these style here */
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please comment on the code above explaining what it does (ideally line by line), so other users were able to understand it without external tools. Thank you!

Comment: it just reset default css of ul tag.

Comment: @Ryu **EDIT** your answer to include that, don't write it as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're having is due to the margin added automatically to the `ul` element:
[image]

Just add `margin-top: 0;` to the `ul` and you'll be good:
[image]

FYI: This margin is set by the [user agent stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#user-agent_stylesheets). Some devs will set `margin: 0;` on whatever elements they want to reset, or use [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css), to override the default values that are provided. It can help prevent unexpected issues like the one you encountered here.

Comment: Does margin get inherited? Why did the margin add there?

Comment: @RichardStrott -- I clarified in my answer. It's because of the [user agent stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#user-agent_stylesheets) provided by default by the browser

Comment: Oh, sorry I totally overlooked the text below the images. Thanks for clarifying. This is all good to know.

Comment: No worries. I just learned about this myself. I kind of knew it before, but not formally. Best advice for this kind of stuff on the front-end is to become very familiar with the dev tools. The size/position/padding/etc box under the style declarations saves my bacon everyday.